# Docker Container run -d flag

Tags: docker, containers

I am running docker run container command in 2 ways

1. `docker container run 4e5021d210f6`

   - It shows container exited N seconds ago on running docker container ls -a
2. `docker container run -d 4e5021d210f6`

   - It also shows container exited N seconds ago on running docker container ls -a 
     but do get some long string "954f102a3c83f6fb7c83189415448c4bb101ff1afe775f2d9b7b4cd70f4e137e" (I do not know what is this number)

what is the difference between the execution of command 1 and command 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-d` will run the container in the background. It's the same as adding `--detach`. What is being printed when you use `-d` is the container's ID.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/

Comment: if the container is running in background then why docker container ls -a show exited....it should status as UP and Running

Comment: Are you certain that whatever is running in your container isn't crashing or shutting down almost immediately after starting?

Comment: may be i can try running something under the container and see it crashes or not...was just trying to understand the purpose of -d flag

Comment: It's simply stopping your container from using your current command line for input and output (`stdin`/`stdout`). It's "detached," now running in the background.

Comment: Did you find that this answer addressed your question adequately?

Comment: Yes.....i am very new to docker so this question might be silly for many....but  yeah i got my answer.... understood how exactly different commands work...Thanks for your help too

Comment: @HarryS Can you accept this answer if it satisfied your question? thanks!

Comment: There isn't an accepted answer at the moment. You have to click the check mark below the voting arrows to accept an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You must use 
`docker ps`
 to see containers running id, status etc, you can also use 
`docker run -it image_name bash` 
if you want to run commands through your terminal inside the container. 
`-d` option is mostly used when you have defined some operations with a Dockerfile and you don't want to interact with the container. So, you run your image's container in --detach (-d) mode, to run in the background.

Notice, that you have to perform `docker stop container_id` in order to stop it.

Answer (score 1):

The `-d` parameter indicates to Docker that you do not want to attach to the container through stdin/out. In other words, you are asking to run the container in a background, non-interactive mode. The string printed is the unique ID of the newly created container which you can use with commands like `docker inspect`

In either command you're executing, your containers are only running for a very short amount of time before stopping. This can be because the container requires arguments to `docker run`, or because the container performs a one-time task or job before exiting. Therefore, the end-result you observe is the same. If the `-d` were omitted and the container ran for a longer amount of time you would see this more clearly